# React router shows blank page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I am trying to get started with react-router.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import HelloWorld from './pages/HelloWorld';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory,browserHistory} from "react-router";
...
const app = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld/>, app);
```

Here dummy class HelloWorld:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class HelloWorld extends Component {
  render(){
      return(<h1> HelloWorld </h1>);
  }
}

export default HelloWorld;
```

Using this setting everything works out fine. However, using routes I end up having a blank page.

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Router history = {hashHistory}>
    <Route path ="/" component={HelloWorld}>
    </Route>
</Router>,
app);
```

Where is the mistake? I searched stackoverflow but no answer seems to be suitable.

Whats really weird for me, is that the following code also results in a blank page:

```
const Routes = () => (
  <Router history = {browserHistory}>
    <Route path ="/" render={ () => (<h1> HelloWorld </h1>) } />
  </Router>
);
const app = document.getElementById('app')
ReactDOM.render(<Routes/>, app);
```

Comment: you are exporting `Featured` but your class is called `HelloWorld`.

Comment: If what @Chris suggested is just a typo and is not in your actual code, then we need to know which version of React-router you are using

Comment: Hi,  i am using v 4.1.2 ( react-router": "^4.1.2). And yes, the wrong export was just a typo!

Comment: can you try updating `<Route path ="/" component={HelloWorld}>
    </Route>` to  `<Route path="/" component={HelloWorld}>
          <IndexRoute component={HelloWorld}/>          
        </Route>`

Comment: Hey, these changes result as well in an blank page

Comment: try <Route path ="/" exact component={HelloWorld} />

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You're using using the V4 in a V3 way.

Instead of

```
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory,browserHistory} from "react-router";
```

Import dependencies in this way:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router";
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory"  // browser history moved into a standalone package since v4.
```

Comment: Still results in a blank page

Answer (score 0):

Ok "one" solution is:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, IndexRoute,hashHistory,browserHistory} from "react-router-dom";
...
const Routes = () => (
   <Router history = {browserHistory}>
    <Route path ='/' component={ Layout } />
   </Router>
);

const app = document.getElementById('app')
ReactDOM.render(<Routes/>, app);
```

Answer (score 0):

99% sure your issue is that your  tag has a relative link. Make it absolute.

```
<!-- do this -->
<script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
<!-- not -->
<script src="static/bundle.js"></script>
<!-- or -->
<script src="./static/bundle.js"></script
```

Answer (score 0):

use this typejust click two pages

```
import{ BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Routes}  from 'react-router-dom'

  
function App() {
const [page, setPage] = useState('');

return (
<div className="App">
  
  <button onClick={() => setPage("about")}>to scold</button>
  <button onClick={()=>setPage('hello')}>to hello</button>
  <Router>
    <Routes>
    <Route element= {<Hello/>} path="/hello"/>
    </Routes>
 
  </Router>
</div>
);
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).